# How can @HttpPost methods ingest complex JSON from webhooks?

Tags: rest-api, integration, json, rest-service

I'm integrating Square with SFDC, and Square has nice webhooks (https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/customers-api/webhooks/customer.created) that it sends for any event on its platform. When a customer is created, for example, it sends the payload below.

I have the webhook sent to a REST API method such as below:

```
global class SquareService{    
    @HttpPost
    global static void CreateCustomer(*parameter here*){            
              //code here
    }
}
```

I just don't know how to define the parameters for the method, because the webhook JSON below has to be explicitly parsed into Apex as a pretty ugly list of extended classes, and when I do try to use one of those classes defined as "Cust", I get:

```
global methods do not support parameter type of SquareService.Cust
```

Appreciate the help as always. Cheers.

Square payload sent to SFDC REST API:

```
   {
      "merchant_id": "MLVA9WV6PHTBD",
      "type": "customer.created",
      "event_id": "841dd10e-21dd-4045-b290-7d7e92f85565",
      "created_at": "2021-06-16T07:00:05.483381293Z",
      "data": {
        "type": "customer",
        "id": "QPTXM8PQNX3Q726ZYHPMNP46XC",
        "object": {
          "customer": {
            "address": {
              "address_line_1": "1018 40th Street",
              "administrative_district_level_1": "CA",
              "locality": "Oakland",
              "postal_code": "94608"
            },
            "birthday": "1962-03-04T00:00:00-00:00",
            "created_at": "2020-11-09T21:23:25.519Z",
            "creation_source": "DIRECTORY",
            "email_address": "jenkins+smorly@squareup.com",
            "family_name": "Smorly",
            "given_name": "Jenkins",
            "group_ids": [
              "JGJCW9S0G68NE.APPOINTMENTS"
            ],
            "id": "QPTXM8PQNX3Q726ZYHPMNP46XC",
            "phone_number": "+12126668929",
            "preferences": {
              "email_unsubscribed": false
            },
            "updated_at": "2020-11-09T21:23:25Z",
            "version": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Ugly JSON2Apex code:

```
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//
// The supplied json has fields with names that are not valid in apex
// and so can only be parsed with explicitly generated code, this option
// was auto selected for you.



    public class Cust {
        public String merchant_id {get;set;} 
        public String type {get;set;} 
        public String event_id {get;set;} 
        public String created_at {get;set;} 
        public Data data {get;set;} 

        public Cust(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'merchant_id') {
                            merchant_id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'type') {
                            type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'event_id') {
                            event_id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'created_at') {
                            created_at = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'data') {
                            data = new Data(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Cust consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Address {
        public String address_line_1 {get;set;} 
        public String administrative_district_level_1 {get;set;} 
        public String locality {get;set;} 
        public String postal_code {get;set;} 

        public Address(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'address_line_1') {
                            address_line_1 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'administrative_district_level_1') {
                            administrative_district_level_1 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'locality') {
                            locality = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'postal_code') {
                            postal_code = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Address consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Customer {
        public Address address {get;set;} 
        public String birthday {get;set;} 
        public String created_at {get;set;} 
        public String creation_source {get;set;} 
        public String email_address {get;set;} 
        public String family_name {get;set;} 
        public String given_name {get;set;} 
        public List<String> group_ids {get;set;} 
        public String id {get;set;} 
        public String phone_number {get;set;} 
        public Preferences preferences {get;set;} 
        public String updated_at {get;set;} 
        public Integer version {get;set;} 

        public Customer(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'address') {
                            address = new Address(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'birthday') {
                            birthday = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'created_at') {
                            created_at = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'creation_source') {
                            creation_source = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'email_address') {
                            email_address = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'family_name') {
                            family_name = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'given_name') {
                            given_name = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'group_ids') {
                            group_ids = arrayOfString(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'id') {
                            id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'phone_number') {
                            phone_number = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'preferences') {
                            preferences = new Preferences(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'updated_at') {
                            updated_at = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'version') {
                            version = parser.getIntegerValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Customer consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Object_Z {
        public Customer customer {get;set;} 

        public Object_Z(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'customer') {
                            customer = new Customer(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Object_Z consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Data {
        public String type {get;set;} 
        public String id {get;set;} 
        public Object_Z object_Z {get;set;} // in json: object

        public Data(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'type') {
                            type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'id') {
                            id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'object') {
                            object_Z = new Object_Z(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Data consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Preferences {
        public Boolean email_unsubscribed {get;set;} 

        public Preferences(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'email_unsubscribed') {
                            email_unsubscribed = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Preferences consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    
    public static Cust parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return new Cust(parser);
    }
    
    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }

    private static List<String> arrayOfString(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<String> res = new List<String>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(p.getText());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution to this is to preprocess the JSON body before deserializing it to the custom top level class. You should not need to use the JSON parser.

The likely offender is

```
"object"
```

as `object` is a reserved word and can't be used as a variable name

So, on the JSON body, preprocess it with

```
body = body.replace('"object":','"objectX":');
```

and then your class for `"data"` looks like

```
class MyTopLevelClass {
  String merchant_id;
  ...
  Data data;
}

class Data {
  ...
  ObjectX objectX;

}

class ObjectX {
   Customer customer;
}

etc...
```

and you can deserialize directly into an object of the top level class

```
   MyTopLevelClass top = (MyTopLevelClass) (JSON.deserialize(body,MyTopLevelClass.class);
```

The only time the JSON parser is required is when the input is a variable structure - e.g. when a JSON property can be an object of different types or an array one time and an object another time, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've preprocessed JSON before when receiving it in a response to a callout, but here I am building a REST API with a method that needs to receive the raw JSON before I can process it. Maybe I'm missing something really simple, but what can I put in as the parameter for the HttpPost method?

global class SquareService{    
    @HttpPost
    global static void CreateCustomer(*parameter here*){            
              //code here
    }
}

Comment: Don't use the parameter as that does an automatic deserialization into that parameter. Instead, get the body from `RestContext.request`

Comment: Ha! Of course, always something simple - for anyone reading this post, it looks like this:

@HttpPost
    global static void CreateCustomer(){  
        
     system.debug('hit CreateCustomer post');
        
        SquareCustomerClass NewCustomer = (SquareCustomerClass) system.JSON.deserialize(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString().replace('object','Object1') , SquareCustomerClass.class);     
         system.debug(JSON.serializePretty(NewCustomer) );

Comment: glad this worked for you ... as a service to the Community,  you should mark as 'answered' when (or if) you were satisfied